# Query nested model with multiple plucks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was just wondering if the following is possible: I have model with nested associative models. I want to be able to `render json:` on `current_user.reports.minned` and have it `eager_load` the plucked values from each model. How can I accomplish this?

Here I use only 2 models as an example. In reality, the solution needs to work for n+1 nested models.

Does not work:

```
class Report
  has_many :templates

  def minned
    self.pluck(:id, :title)
    self.templates = templates.minned
  end
end

class Template
  belongs_to :report

  def minned
    self.pluck(:id, :name, :sections, :columns)
  end
end

....

# reports.minned.limit(limit).offset(offset)
# This should return something like:
[{
  'id': 0,
  'title': 'Rep',
  'templates': [{
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Temp'
    'sections': [],
    'columns': []
  }]
},
{
  'id': 1,
  'title': 'Rep 1',
  'templates': [{
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Temp',
    'sections': [],
    'columns': []
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Temp 1',
    'sections': [],
    'columns': []
  }]
}]
```

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

I will add that I found a way to do this by overriding `as_json` for each model, but this applies the plucking to all requests. I need to have control over which requests give what pieces of information.

```
# in Report model
def as_json(options={})
  super(:id, :title).merge(templates: templates)
end

# in Template model
def as_json(options={})
  super(:id, :name, :sections, :columns)
end
```

Thanks to eirikir, this is all I need to do:

## Report model

```
def self.minned
  includes(:templates).as_json(only: [:id, :title], include: {templates: {only: [:id, :name, :sections, :columns]}})
end
```

Then when using this with pagination order, limit or anything like that, just drop it at the end:

```
  paginate pre_paginated_reports.count, max_per_page do |limit, offset|
    render json: pre_paginated_reports.order(id: :desc).limit(limit).offset(offset).minned
  end
```

Now I'm not overriding `as_json` and have complete control over the data I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to achieve this specifying the output in the options given to `as_json`:

```
current_user.reports.includes(:templates).as_json(only: [:id, :title], include: {templates: {only: [:id, :name, :sections, :columns]}})
```

Comment: If I recall correctly this is basically what I was originally doing. But I wanted a more method based way of doing all of this. I will try working out a definition of a method based on what you just gave, and will report back.

Comment: `more method based way of doing all of this` -- what do you mean by this? You can certainly move the above into a `self.as_minned_json` method in the `Report` model...

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for getting me to think about it in this way again. I defined a method from the point of `includes` and onward, and that worked. I will update my post to show using my example.